# Generalizing infinite q - Pochammer symbols to more q symbols

Tags: special-functions

The (infinite) [q-Pochhammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) symbols are defined as

$$(a;q)_{\infty} := \prod_{k=0}^{\infty}(1-aq^{k})$$

I am interested a natural generalization of this symbol to multiple q's. In specific the 2 D and 3D cases which are defined as,

For 2 symbols q,r

$$(a;q,r)_{\infty} := \prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\prod_{l=0}^{\infty}(1-aq^{k}r^{l})$$

For 3 symbols q,r,s

$$(a;q,r,s)_{\infty} := \prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\prod_{l=0}^{\infty}\prod_{m=0}^{\infty}(1-aq^{k}r^{l}s^{m})$$

We can assume that $$|q|<1,|r|<1,|s|<1$$ for cases of interest.

I searched if they are discussed in the literature, but I could not find any leads. These generalizations naturally appear in the [Grand Canonical partition function for fermions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_canonical_ensemble) in a harmonic trap

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: It seems to me that the generalization would be $\textstyle\displaystyle{(a;q_1,\dots,q_n)_{\infty}:=\prod_{k_1,\dots,k_n\geq 0}\left(1-a\prod_{i=1}^{n}q_i^{k_i}\right)}$

Comment: @RounakSarkar I am interested in simplifications and insights into the said formulas and pointers to standard results from literature.

That is a valid way to generalize, but I am not interested in that for my problems of interest.

Comment: Correction I misread and Did not notice the sub script i in $q_i$. Yes that is exactly what I am thinking about.

Comment: So that is a part of your answer. The other thing you want is basically some identities about it right??

Comment: Yes, I am looking for Identities

Comment: Borcherds Products may be relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290794/wherefore-art-thou-a-borcherds-product https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404427.pdf